# Quick but not simple question. $2^\sqrt2$ or e, which is greater?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

> $2^\sqrt2$ vs $e$, which is greater?

$(2^\sqrt2)^\sqrt2 = 4\quad $  &  $\quad e^\sqrt2$ = ?

$\log(2^\sqrt2) = \sqrt2\log(2)\quad$ & $\quad \log(e) = 1$

I tried but can't induce comparable form.

Is anybody know how to prove it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: 2^√2 > e or 2^√2 < e ? is my question

Comment: Well, the solution to $2^x=e$ is $x=\frac 1{\ln 2}\approx 1.4427>\sqrt 2$.  Of course, numerical computation is involved in that.

Comment: What's wrong with using a calculator?

Comment: Oh, that's simple but good idea. THX

Comment: Hm. you guys are right. I'd better use calculator.

Comment: Now you've confused me.  Either you have a calculator, and the question becomes, "why didn't you use your calculator", or you're not allowed a calculator (and you should have clarified that from the beginning).

Comment: Sorry my bad. At first I thought there is a non-computational approach I couldn't find. If there is, I wanted to know. Now I recieved answers which I was intended at first. So I'm fine. At first I didn't think about computational approach but when I heard it first time, I thought it's a good idea also. That's it.

Comment: I attempted a different proof by rearranging the series expansions of $\ln2$ and $2^{-1/2}$ and managed to show that the inequality is equivalent to $\sum_{i=8}^\infty\frac{1}{2i+1}\left[\binom{-1/2}{2i}-\frac{1}{i+1}\right]<0.0268$ but couldn't proceed further. The summands are monotonically decreasing, so if anyone can suggest an upper bound, it could help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the same as comparing $\frac{3}{2}\log(2)$ and $1$. Since $x(1-x)$ is non-negative and bounded by $\frac{1}{4}$ on $(0,1)$, we have
$$ 0\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2(1-x)^2}{1+x}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{16}$$
where the middle integral is exactly $-\frac{11}{4}+4\log(2)$. It follows that 
$$ \frac{33}{32} \leq \frac{3}{2}\log(2) \leq \frac{135}{128} $$
so $\frac{3}{2}\log(2)>1$ and $\color{red}{2\sqrt{2}>e}$.
 This proof just requires a polynomial division, perfectly doable by hand.

About $\sqrt{2}\log(2)$, we have
$$ \log(2)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\leq\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k-1}}\stackrel{\text{CS}}{\leq}\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt{n\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)}$$
and the RHS is *exactly* $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. This is just a slick application of creative telescoping and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: It's $2^\sqrt2$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1175784)

Comment: @YuiToCheng: well, I dealt with both cases.

Comment: +1. I think your answer truly doesn't require any numerical calculation.

Comment: (+1), slick answer as always. For posterity, and since the last step had confused me for a while, rewrite the sum as $\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k-1}}=\sum1\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{k(k-1)}}$ before applying CS.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of comparing $2^{\sqrt 2}$ and $e$, let's raise both to $\sqrt 2$ and compare $2^2$ and $e^{\sqrt 2}$:
$$
e^{\sqrt 2} > 2.7^{1.4} \approx 4.017068799 > 4 = 2^2
$$
Or use that
$$
e^x > 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}
$$
with $x=1.41$ and get
$$
e^{\sqrt 2} > e^{1.41} > 4.03594 > 4
$$
In fact, $e^{\sqrt 2} \approx 4.113250377 > 4$.

Comment: I don't understand how you can estimate $2.7^{1.4}$, $e^{1.41}$, and $e^{\sqrt 2}$ without a calculator.  And if you have a calculator, why not find $2^{\sqrt 2}$ from the beginning?

Comment: @Teepeemm, you're right. The best approach is the second one, with a polynomial. Unfortunately, it's of degree $4$ and you have to use two decimals in $x=1.41$.

Answer (score 6):

If you know that $\ln(2)\approx0.69$ and $1/\sqrt2=\sqrt2/2\approx1.414/2=0.707$, then you have $\ln(2)\lt1/\sqrt2$, in which case $\ln(2^\sqrt2)=\sqrt2\ln2\lt1=\ln(e)$, hence $2^\sqrt2\lt e$.

It's not hard to show that $\sqrt2\gt1.4$, since $1.4^2=1.96\lt2$.  It's a little trickier to show that $\ln(2)\lt0.7$, but this can be done by comparing the area beneath the curve $y=1/x$ to the areas of the trapezoids containing it with endpoints at $x=1$, $4/3$, $5/3$, and $2$:

$$\ln(2)=\int_1^2{dx\over x}\lt{1\over6}\left(1+2\cdot{3\over4}+2\cdot{3\over5}+{1\over2} \right)={1\over6}\left(1+{3\over2}+{6\over5}+{1\over2} \right)={1\over6}\cdot{42\over10}={7\over10}$$

Comment: Nice solution because this does not require a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

$2\sqrt{2}^2 = 8$

$e^2 < 2.8*2.8 = 7.84$

You're welcome

Comment: It's $2^\sqrt2$...

Comment: Aww, there is a bug in EE. Yellow formula in startpost is $2\sqrt{2}$ for me.

Comment: I see. It's not your fault. Corrected. It's a careless typo.

Comment: One can start with taylor of $e^x$ then. $1+x+...+\frac{x^5}{120}$, where x is $1.4 < \sqrt{2}$. Sum of it gives 4.042219. Can be calculated by hand. $1.4 < \sqrt{2}$ is trivial.

Comment: Yeah, it's exactly the summary of the first answer.

Comment: Sorry guys. I typed at first 2^√2. But somebody edited. I have to know how to write math symbols. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\ln(x),\,g(x)=x^{-1/2}$. By the Taylor series of $e^x$, we have

$$e^{-0.35}>1-0.35+\frac12\left(0.35\right)^2-\frac16\left(0.35\right)^3=0.704>0.7$$

Hence, $g(e^{0.7})-f(e^{0.7})=e^{-0.35}-0.7>0$. Applying Taylor series again shows

$$e^{0.7}>1+0.7+\frac{1}{2}(0.7)^2+\frac{1}{6}(0.7)^3=2.002>2$$

Observe that $f$ and $g$ are respectively strictly increasing and decreasing over $(0,\infty)$, so $g>f$ holds for all $x$ in $(0,2.002)$. Therefore $g(2)>f(2)$, which rearranges to $e>2^{\sqrt{2}}$. These calculations are perfectly feasible to do by hand.

Comment: Addendum: it's not feasible to use the series expansion of $\ln(x)$ vs. $x^{-1/2}$, nor  $\ln(x)$ vs. the reciprocal of the series expansion of $x^{1/2}$ to compare their values at $x=2$ as you'd have to go to at least $37$ and $23$ terms, respectively.